# Developing visualization on zip code level data

Tags: maps, gis, visualization, zipcode

I'm trying to use the zip code data from the census (any year that works). I have 5-digit zip code data that I need to match up to a map/shape file. The problem is that the zip code tabulation files from the Censsus ZCTA that can be found here http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/layers.cgi have holes in them. I am assuming these are lakes, parks, and wilderness areas. However, every zip code map I've seen do not have these. Is there a resource or method of combining these to create a solid zip code area?

Also, are there any other alternatives to zip code tabulation areas? Google maps will not work for what I am doing unfortunately. :(

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you want to do. If you are just showing a map, pick a background color other than white so those areas don't stand out. If you are trying to get a zip code for a location, do some sort of "close to" algorithm to find a nearby zip. It sort of depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I am aggregating zip codes based on the data I have. I was hoping that some of these regions would be absorbed by other zip codes so when they are aggregated (based on the data I have) it would show different regions without these holes.

Comment: Have you tried gis.se?

Comment: I think they also have state (and county) boundary data. If you add that, you can identify the parts in a state that aren't in a zip.

Answer (score 0):

Validating your assumption about the holes in your coverage, according to [the Census Bureau information on Zip Code Tabulation Areas](http://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html): `For the 2010 Census, large water bodies and large unpopulated land areas do not have ZCTAs.`

Although zip codes really aren't area features, just mail routing constructs, there are other zip code shapefiles that cover the contiguous US.  See this GIS StackExchange post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/most-up-to-date-source-for-us-zip-code-boundaries for pointers to them.